# Call exception at hbase docker

Tags: docker, connection, hbase, local

I've created a docker image of the hbase(zookeeper embedded).
Also, I've created a docker image of my application(base image:tomcat).

With docker-compose I've started two containers(my_app, hbase)
It works fine.
But when I tried to run a container(hbase) in docker and run my_app from local with tomcat. my_app is getting repeated Call exception, 

`Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38358 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'ApplicationIndex,,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=da996582a9e5,39095,1525328219005, seqNum=0 
Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38358 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'ApplicationIndex,,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=da996582a9e5,39095,1525328219005, seqNum=0`

I don't think there is a problem with docker-compose file or my hbase-site.xml file since all is fine when my_app is running inside the docker.

I'm assuming that(since region and host name exists in my_app log(above), and zookeeper(embedded in hbase) responds when my_app starts up) there isn't any problem connecting to zookeeper and hbase from my_app. But has problem while hbase replying to my_app.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

docker-compose file is as below.

```
hbase:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      - HBASE_VERSION=${HBASE_VERSION}
  container_name: ${HBASE_NAME}

  networks:
    - networks

  expose:
    # zookeeper
    - "2181"
    # HBase Master API port
    - "60000"
    # HBase Master Web UI
    - "16010"
    # Regionserver API port
    - "60020"
    # HBase Regionserver web UI
    - "16030"
  ports:
    - 2180:2181
    - 60000:60000
    - 16010:16010
    - 60020:60020
    - 16030:16030
```

Comment: Although I'm not in favour of using `--privileged` mode, maybe you could use to do a test. Is possible that your app is trying to do unprivileged calls. Try the same adding to docker compose service option: `privileged: true` and let's see.

Comment: @ Alex Galera Thank you for the comment. I'd really like to try. But couldn't make the time to try it out. I'll get back to this ASAP.